# How can i make the `col-sm-4` regain the entire space of `col-sm-5` when its hidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am hiding my col-sm-5 on tablet mode by using `hidden-sm`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i make the `col-sm-4` regain the entire space of `col-sm-5` when its hidden?.

Comment: From my experience, it happens automatically, see: http://www.madhur.co.in/

Comment: It's redundant to assign both col-sm-5 and hidden-sm, since .hidden-sm makes .col-sm-5 disappear. On what devices do you want to show/hide the col-5 div?

Answer (score 2):

this should work.
 `hidden-sm` hides in small devices not tablets.so have `hiddem-md`
.Link for visibility classes in bootstrap -[Link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-9">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 hidden-md ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the visibility stack ranges from small automatically in bootstrap so you are just overloading all of the views with smalls when you should capitalize on how it differentiates medium large and xl:

if you want the same content make the class "col-sm-4 col-md-5" and it will switch automatically based on screen/device size

if you want different content then use Sai's answer above